# How to change primaryColor globally?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am using material ui for e-learning project. I have got issue on change primary/secondary color sitewide. How can i set primary color globally? 
I have check this [**link**](https://material-ui.com/customization/themes/)

```js
import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      // light: will be calculated from palette.primary.main,
      main: '#ff4400',
      // dark: will be calculated from palette.primary.main,
      // contrastText: will be calculated to contrast with palette.primary.main
    },
    secondary: {
      light: '#0066ff',
      main: '#0044ff',
      // dark: will be calculated from palette.secondary.main,
      contrastText: '#ffcc00',
    },
    // error: will use the default color
  },
});
```

it will work as individual component but i need to apply for all components changing in One place?

Is there any good idea to achieve?

Comment: are you using `MuiThemeProvider` multiple times i mean in each file (to wrap the material ui components)???

Comment: hmmm.. no ............

Comment: if you are using only once (in index.js or app.js in starting point) then that theme should be globally available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have done is correct.
In order to have this is globally put your app wrapped with `MuiThemeProvider` blocks

as an example:

```
import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { MuiThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      // light: will be calculated from palette.primary.main,
      main: '#ff4400',
      // dark: will be calculated from palette.primary.main,
      // contrastText: will be calculated to contrast with palette.primary.main
    },
    secondary: {
      light: '#0066ff',
      main: '#0044ff',
      // dark: will be calculated from palette.secondary.main,
      contrastText: '#ffcc00',
    },
    // error: will use the default color
  },
});

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        < your application code >
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
```

Hope this will help you.